# Sort months chronologically in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have my data which consists of only two columns like below (the data is available for 12 months) -

| Months | count of employees |
| --- | --- |
| January | 3455 |
| February | 2236 |
| March | 3546 |
| April | 23423 |

and so on...

I tried to sort by creating another column of "month_number" and then -

**selected the month column -> Column tools -> Sort by column -> "month_number"**

but it gives an error of **circular dependency**

could someone please help me in sorting the chart my months

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you add your `month_number` column in PowerQuery (Transform Data) instead, it will work. When you add a calculated column to sort, it can throw this error due to Power BI modeling engine semantics on dependency.

Comment: I am unsure about the approach, so now I am at power query (Transform data), then ? how can I add the column

Comment: @Zeren https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/add-conditional-column